# overwrite FALSE with NA

Tags: r, replace, na

I want to replace the FALSE values with NA's.
I'm sure that the solution is easy but I don't get it.
Thanks for your help!

```
abc<-c(1,2,5,6,7)
abcd<-c(1,2,5,6)
test<-abc %in% abcd
table(test)["FALSE"]
```

The solution should look like this:

```
abc <- c(1, 2, 5, 6, NA)
```

Answer (score 3):

```
abc[match(abc, abcd)]
[1]  1  2  5  6 NA
```

`%in%` actively avoids this behavior, the complete code for `%in%` is:

```
`%in%` <- function (x, table) {
    match(x, table, nomatch = 0L) > 0L
}
```

The `nomatch = 0L` changes the output `NA` to `FALSE`. The default `match` behavior includes it.

Comment: Thanks for the quick and detailed answer!

Answer (score 2):

Simply do-

```
> abc[!(abc %in% abcd)] <- NA
```

**Output-**

```
> abc
[1]  1  2  5  6 NA
```

Answer (score 0):

Try base functions

```
   test[isFalse(test)] <- NA
```